# Selenium Webdriver with Chrome dont load Widevine Content Decryption Module on MacOS

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, widevine

I have a problem with chrome not loading the "Widevine Content Decryption Module" under "chrome://plugins/" when i run my test suites in the MacOS operating system, but it's working fine on linux and windows machines. So it's kind of a way chromedriver opens the browser in MacOS as it seems.

Also under "chrome://components/" there is no item, compared to the ones I have when I run chrome manually

I have the following line in my test suite (writed in the Ruby language):

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that under MacOS, chromedriver flag "disable-component-update" blocks "Widevine Content Decryption Module".

I've solved it adding this lines to the webdriver selection section of my test suites:

```
            caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"excludeSwitches" => [ "disable-component-update" ]})
            @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

And I can now playback DRM content on MacOS with Selenium.